# PHP system() and exec() functions not working with temp files

Tags: php, web-services

I'm using the `system()` function in PHP to call a CLI program that I need to use that is not currently available from within PHP (code below). I'm using xml2brl (liblouisxml) CLI to generate an output file that contains braille ASCII text. Using the code below, the two files are successfully created, and the first file has the input text successfully written to it; however, the output file (the second file) never gets the translated text written to it.

Here's the strange part, though. Using the same command that is passed to `system()` and the same temp files that I create in PHP, I can successfully run the command as my user in Terminal. What could this issue be caused by? When I run `whoami` command through `system()`, I get my user, and no special permissions are required for either the temp files or the CLI command `xml2brl`.

Currently, I'm creating two temp files in PHP:

```
//Create the temporary files that will be passed to xml2brl
$_standardText = tempnam("~/tmp", "pll_");
$_translatedText = tempnam("~/tmp", "pll_");
```

The temp files are stored in /private/tmp, and have the `pll_` prefix to them, to identify the files that the PHP script is creating.

Then, I'm writing the contents of the passed text to the temp file like this:

```
//Write the contents of the passed text to the temp file
$handle = fopen($_standardText, "w");
fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($handle);
```

Now, the temp file located in `/private/tmp/xxxx` has the text written in it (verified this), and then I go ahead and format the command:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("xml2brl -p" . " " . $_standardText . " " .  $_translatedText);
```

This has the format like this when echoing the $command variable:

```
xml2brl -p /private/tmp/pll_MYRy9m /private/tmp/pll_DmiK7E
```

And go ahead and run the exec command, which should process the input file and write the translated text to the output file, but it doesn't:

```
exec($command);
```

Now, here's the strange part... when I try to do just an `ls`, I can get the directory listing from my home directory and echo that out through the PHP script -- signifying that I should have access to run the system and exec commands with Apache, but whenever this command runs, it doesn't work. However, when I don't delete the temp files, and use the same PHP-created command (`xml2brl -p /private/tmp/pll_MYRy9m /private/tmp/pll_DmiK7E`)and temp files in the CLI, I can run them under my user.

Comment: have you tried getting the return var of exec()?  exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] ) http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I just checked, and when I include a return_var, I get a value of "1" when running that command.

Comment: seems like an error. how about the output? have you checked it?

Comment: I'm sorry, the return code is `127` from the `exec` I don't have any output in the output array.

Comment: i think it means "command not found". So maybe xml2brl is not in the PATH yet for the user being used by your app when executing it.

Comment: try including the complete path for xml2brl first and let us know of the result. something like $command = escapeshellcmd("/opt/local/bin/xml2brl -p" . " " . $_standardText . " " .  $_translatedText);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do (after making sure your script can run simple commands such as `/bin/ls`) is make full use of `exec()`'s arguments:

```
exec($command, $out, $code);
if ($code) {
    // an error occurred while running the command
}
```

Second, make sure the paths are correct. `xml2brl` may be in your path, but perhaps not in the path of your script:

```
$command = '/usr/bin/xml2brl -p ' . escapeshellarg($_standardText);

exec($command, $out, $code);
if ($code) {
    die("An error occurred while attempting torun xml2brl");
} else {
    echo "Output was: ", join("\n", $out);
}
```

If that still doesn't work, you can redirect `stderr`:

```
exec("$command 2>&1", $out, $code);
```

Comment: I get "An error occurred while attempting to run xml2brl". I think that the `$PATH` may be wrong. How can I set this to work correctly in my path?

Comment: @coryb Easy, work out the absolute path of the command and use that; no need to set the PATH environment variable.

Comment: When including the full path to the command, I still get the same issue. Could there be a permissions problem with the xml2brl command? Currently, it's set to `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin`.

Comment: When you tried `"$command 2>&1"` did `$out` contain any useful information?

Comment: Looks like it may be an issue with `xml2brl`: `Array ( [0] => dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib [1] => Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/xml2brl [2] => Reason: Incompatible library version: xml2brl requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0 )` Strange thing is that everything works correctly when I'm manually using the command.

Comment: @coryb This could be a problem with the dynamic loader, since the environment of your script is not the same as when you're logged in. You could check that on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0):

Include error_reporting(E_ALL); at beginning of script to see if there's any warnings that your not catching. chmod xml2brl to 777 to ensure that apache can execute it. Just out of curiosity, where is xml2brl located? ensure that apache has access to this directory. You said that you can do it yourself via a term, are you positive that apache made those files if you have also been doing it manually?

Make sure apache has read and write access to the temp files, and make sure apache has accesses to and permission to execute xml2brl.

Comment: No other errors are being reporded using `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. The xml2brl program is in `/opt/local/bin/`. When I'm running the command myself manually, I'm using the same files that are being created by the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

try including the complete path for xml2brl first in your command and let us know of the result. something like

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("/opt/local/bin/xml2brl -p" . " " . $_standardText . " " . $_translatedText);
```

Comment: When including the full path to the command, I still get the same issue. Could there be a permissions problem with the xml2brl command? Currently, it's set to `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin`.

Comment: are you getting the same return var?