# PHP shell_exec() not working for some commands like wc

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu

I have ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.3,Apache2 installed.
I needed to count the words in a doc file using php and pdf.
while i am able to do shell_exec for text to pdf but not for wc.
here is the code

```
    <?php
    $content = shell_exec('pdftotext test.pdf -');
    echo str_word_count($content);// this is working

    $word_count = exec('wc -w test.doc'); //this is not working
    echo $word_count;
    ?>
```

However the code works in command line.

Comment: Most likely a permission problem. Look up what permissions does `wc` use and what permission does your *php* user have.

Comment: Why not use `shell_exec` for `wc` as well instead of using `exec`?

Comment: I'll add to this by saying that I have yet to come across a problem with PHP `exec()` that ISN'T a permission issue.

Comment: Could also be a path problem.  Try using the full path to the binaries in addition to using something other than `exec`.  Personally I prefer [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open), but that's more complex than you need here.

Comment: i have also tried with the fullpath and exec() but with no success.

Comment: I have given all the permission 777 to wc but still no success.Another thing i would like to state which might help.
When i give the exec('wc -w ') or shell_exec('wc -w ') its giving an output 0. So i guess the command is working.

Comment: @charles can you use proc_open for the same as a example.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851428/php-system-and-exec-functions-not-working-with-temp-files/13851775#13851775) may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there was a problem with my ubuntu Release 12.04.
I tried it with ubuntu 11.10 and with LAMP.
And everything worked like a charm.
I will reinstall this dist of ubuntu and check again.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

   echo exec('wc -w test.doc;echo $?'); 

?>
```

try this to see what you can get.
if the result is 0,it works,otherwise some error informations will be given.

Comment: No i am just getting a blank without any errors. Another thing to mention its working in command line directly.